# express.static() and sendFile() problem... creating a dynamic host with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

After configure my web server with nginx, i redirected all *.example.com to my nodejs server.

But before, i handle the http request, i check the url and host to see if it is correct or not.

For example, if the user writes something like  what.ever.example.com
I redirect him to the main website because that host is not valid.

otherwise if the user writes something like mydomain.example.com

The user should access to this website and receive the angular APP.

So i am doing something like this.

> UPDATED CODE

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('./server/database');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');

// Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000)

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Routes API
app.use('/api/users', require('./server/routes/usuarios.routes'));
app.use('/api/almacenes', require('./server/routes/almacen.routes'))
app.use('/api/updates', require('./server/routes/update.routes'))
app.use('/api/dominios', require('./server/routes/dominios.routes'))

app.get('/', checkHost);
app.get('/', express.static('../nginx/app'));
app.get('/*', checkPath);

function checkHost(req, res, next) {  //With this function what i pretend is check the subdomain that the user send, and if it doesn't exist. redirect it. 
  var domain = req.headers.host
  subDomain = domain.split('.')
  if (subDomain.length == 3) {
    subDomain = subDomain[0].split("-").join(" ");
    let query = { dominio: subDomain }
    var dominiosModel = mongoose.model('dominios');
    dominiosModel.findOne(query).exec((err, response) => {
      if (response != null) {
        if (response.dominio == subDomain) {
          next();
        } else {
          res.writeHead(303, {
            location: 'http://www.example.com/index.html'
          })
          res.end()
        }
      } else {
        res.writeHead(303, {
          location: 'http://www.example.com/index.html'
        })
        res.end()
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.writeHead(303, {
      location: 'http://www.example.com/index.html'
    })
    res.end()
  }
}

function checkPath(req, res, next) { //With this function what i want to do is.. if the user send *.example.com/whatever, i redirect it to *.example.com
  if (req.url !== '/') {
    res.writeHead(303, {
      location: `http://${req.headers.host}`
    })
    res.end()
  } else {
    next()
  }
}



// Starting Server.
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

All redirects are working well, but when in checkHost the subDomain matched, it doesnt send nothing to the front... so what can i do here?

Comment: I recommend you don't use express.static() inside an app.get(). This is almost always done outside  the route definitions. It also doesn't make sense that you are sending index.html right after you are declaring the folder '../nginx/app/ as static. Any file inside this folder should be automatically accesible through HTTP.

Comment: when i use express.static() outside, i don't understand why i cant get the http request, for example, if i put it outside the app.get('*', checkPath, checkHost, function (req, response) {}) is never reached, so i cant filter the url, thanks for your comment @tutiplain

Comment: also... if the express.static() is outside... if type whatever.example.com i receive always the files, is not matter what subdomain i type... it happens because the app.get('*' is not redirecting the valid or invalid host and url

Comment: Try putting express.static() at the very end. Middleware is called in the order in which it is passed into app.use(), so adding the static() middleware at the end should cause all your requests to pass through all other middleware first.

Comment: Also note that using express.static() there, will result in it being called on every single request, which may lead to performance issues in the future.

Comment: putting the express.static() before the app.listen() is not working... all redirects works but when i send the correct url. the server reach the sendFile but doesnt send the app.

so if you think it will gives me some issues... witch one is the correct way to do it?
It is the first time i am trying to handle dynamic hosts... 

@tutiplain

Comment: I've never handled dynamic hosts myself, I just thought that the way the static middleware is set up looks strange and that might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I would suggest making another middleware function and adding it after checkHost, that simply prints a line. That would make you certain that next() is being called from checkHost().

Comment: yes, that next() is called, i have a console.log that prints checkHost found the subdomain and exectued next()..

Comment: @tutiplain i deleted the express.static() and the sendFile() and i just did a res.write(' hello') in case that the subdomain is found... and it is working... so something is happening with express.static() or sendFile()... oh thank you so much for follow my case, i apreciate it :)

Comment: Reading the Express docs (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) , the .sendFile() function accepts a callback, which means it is probably an async function. How about if you leave your res.sendFile() and remove the response.end()

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the response.end(). Since .sendFile() accepts a callback, it is most likely an async function, which means that calling .end() right after .sendFile() will most probably result in a blank response.

Comment: yes, we almost got it, as you mention sendFile() is an async function, so removing the res.end() is "working" ( If you just want send 1 file ), but in my case im trying to send a whole Angular app... so im forced to use express.static() so something still wrong... i will try to update.

Answer (score 1):

The sendFile function requires absolute path of the file to be sent, if `root` is not provided. If `root` is provided, a relative path could be used, but the `root` itself should be absolute. Check documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

You should try to send your `index.html` in following manner:

```
app.get('*', checkPath, checkHost, function (req, response) {
  response.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../nginx/app') });
}
```

This should work provided that the path `../nginx/app/index.html` is valid, relative to the file in which this code is written.

Additionally, based on the sample code (and the comments), you probably don't need the `express.static(...)` at all. Unless, you need to serve 'other' files statically.

If it is needed, then the `app.use(express.static('../nginx/app'))` should be outside the controller. It should probably be added before the `bodyParser`, but since you are concerned about someone being able to access 'index.html' via the static middleware, you can consider following order for your middlewares:

```
//existing body parser and cors middlewares

// existing /api/* api middlewares. 

app.use(checkPath);
app.use(checkHost);
app.use(express.static('../nginx/app'));
```

If the checkPath middleware is modified slightly to redirect to `/index.html`, the middleware with `'*'` path might not be required at all with this setup.

Comment: i am trying your answer but maybe i keep doing something bad... i updated my question with your suggest

Comment: Your updated code looks fine. Are you at least getting the `index.html` file when the request is sent? If so then, the way index.html references other resources might be incorrect. For eg. a JS file included in index.html should have path `/js/app.js` instead of `../nginx/app/js/app.js`. If the index.html loaded, you can see the exact error in browser console.

Comment: finally it is working i updated it, thank you for your answer, you gave me some tips that were useful. the app.get('*') as you mentioned is not necessary :) event the sendFile aswel, now i am thinking about how to handel several mongodb connections for each subdomain :S